# Error at Data Conversion Transformation when Trying to Convert String from Excel Source to DB_TIMEZONEOFFSET to SQL Server Destination

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, data-conversion, timestamp-with-timezone

Been several years since I had to write an SSIS package and struggling with converting a datetimezone string from Excel to Data Conversion transformation converting to DB_TIMEZONEOFFSET to a SQL Server Destination.

The following is the Timestamp in all 7 rows of Excel source:  [image]

The date column from the Excel source is a `Unicode String [DT_WSTR]` as seen below:

[image]

The SQL Server destination field is setup as `DATETIMEOFFSET(7)` as seen below:

[image]

I am receiving the following errors on the `Data Conversion` transformation when run the data flow:

> [Data Conversion [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiIgb.png)] Error: Data conversion failed while converting
> column "Column1.createdAt" (82) to column "Copy of Column1.createdAt"
> (38).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The
> value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>
> [Data Conversion [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiIgb.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data
> Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of
> Column1.createdAt]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and
> the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion
> Output].Columns[Copy of Column1.createdAt]" specifies failure on
> error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
> component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
> information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
> ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (2) failed with
> error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input"
> (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput
> method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal
> and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error
> messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

It is also important to note that I did also try to use a `Derived Column` transformation before the `Data Conversion` transformation as well to cast as DATETIMEOFFSET(7) to match that of SQL Server destination and received errors there as well similar to above.

Been fighting this for a while now and any extra eyes will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssis cannot do the conversion if there are `T` and `Z` letters in the field. Use the `REPLACE` command to replace the letter `T` with space and the letter `Z` without characters. Like This : `(DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET,7)REPLACE(REPLACE(createdAt,"T"," "),"Z","")`

Comment: SQL Server has a T though?  2022-07-19T16:27:36.2841546-04:00

Comment: Yes that's right. It is accepted in SQL together with T. But not in SSIS. I don't know the architecture of it

Comment: Got it thanks. Gonna give it a go here shortly.

Comment: My bad for taking awhile to mark as answered. This worked.